# Getting error about $pushAll when going to endpoint, but not using it anywhere

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a strange one...

I've developed an api with Node/Express/Mongoose using Mongodb 3.4.9, now it's 3.4.17.

I have no ideal why, but for some reason a block of code I have been using for ages is throwing an error:

```
{name: "MongoError", message: "Unknown modifier: $pushAll", driver: true, index: 0, code: 9,…}
code: 9
driver: true
errmsg: "Unknown modifier: $pushAll"
index: 0
message: "Unknown modifier: $pushAll"
name: "MongoError"
```

Here is the code:

```
router.route('/addemail/:id')

// ADD EMAILS
.put(function(req, res){
  Profile.findOne({'owner_id':req.params.id}, function(err, profile){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);
      profile.emails.push({
        email_type: req.body.email_type,
        email_address: req.body.email_address
      })
    profile.save(function(err){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(profile);
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see, I'm not using $pushAll in this block of code, or actually anywhere in my code.

What else could be causing this???

Thanks for any guru advise.

Update: Here is my model for the profile and I'm including the emails model next:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
// SUBDOCUMENTS
var AddressesSchema = require('./profile/addresses');
var BusinessesSchema = require('./profile/businesses');
var EmailsSchema = require('./profile/emails');
var PhonesSchema = require('./profile/phones');
var SocialSchema = require('./profile/social');




// PROFILE (PARENT) MODEL
var ProfileSchema = new Schema({

    //PROFILE INFO
    owner_id: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
      unique: true
    },
    notice: {
      type: Number, // 1=profile, 2=profile and cards
    },
    first_name:{
      type: String
    },
    last_name:{
      type: String
    },
    initial:{
      type: String
    },
    birthday:{
      type: Date
    },
    highschool:{
      type: String
    },
    college:{
      type: String
    },
    facebook:{
      type: String
    },
    linkedin:{
      type: String
    },
    linkedin_bus:{
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    google: {
      type: String
    },
    pinterest: {
      type: String
    },
    user_image: {
      type: String
    },
    contacts:[{
      type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:'Contact'
    }],

    //SUBDOCUMENTS
    emails:[EmailsSchema],
    phones:[PhonesSchema],
    addresses:[AddressesSchema],
    businesses:[BusinessesSchema],
    social:[SocialSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

Here is what the emails model looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  



// CONTACT (PARENT) MODEL
var EmailSchema = new Schema({

    //CONTACT INFO
    email: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    },
    date_registered: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Email', EmailSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose probably creates a `$pushAll` under the hood which, however, has been removed in newer version of MongoDB as you can see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#remove-pushall-update-operator). So this is why you get the error.

I suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Mongoose which will fix this.

Also see these discussions on the Mongoose repo: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4455
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5574

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me for asking but why don't you just:

```
// ADD EMAILS
.put(function(req, res) {
  Profile.update({'owner_id': req.params.id}, 
    {
      $addToSet: {
        email_type: req.body.email_type,
        email_address: req.body.email_address
    }
  });
});
```

It seems you just want to add an object to an array in a mongo document based on `owner_id`. [**$addToSet**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) does that.

Answer (score 0):

You should get advantage of some mongodb nice features  i.e. you could do these:

```
Profile.findOneAndUpdate({'owner_id':req.params.id},{addToSet:{emails:[ email_type: req.body.email_type, email_address: req.body.email_address]}}, function(err, profile){ 
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
     } else {
        res.json(profile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi vitomadio, I tried what you suggested, but it does not work. I event placed the email type and address {} as the emails array is an array of objects

Comment: Strange, are you getting the same error: could you share your Profile model code?

Comment: Added the main Profile model and the emails model

Comment: Why are you creating email property as a model? why you just do this: emails:[ ], so you could get in what you need, strings, objects, numbers, etc. Besides if you want to insert email property as an object model you have to create it first and only then you could added to the Profile. I'm almost sure that if you change that in your Profile Schema it should works.